# Opencart Information pages not visible

Tags: opencart, footer, information-hiding

I am using opencart 1.5.3.1. None of the Information pages are displayed on the website. I can see the pages and the text in the admin though. Any ideas... please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a multistore setup? Do you have the store checked in the "Links" tab? Are you using a custom theme and do the links show if you switch to the default theme?

Comment: In OpenCart the information pages should be listed in the footer (as you can see in the [demo](http://demo.opencart.com)) and in the information module that you have to install, enable and place on your page(s) - it's the default module that comes with the OC install. In case of custom template it is possible the information pages in footer are not listed. In this case try to enable the information module and place it on some page (e.g. *Home*, to some layout position) and check whether it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Enable it in Admin->Catalog-> Data tab->Status